# How to split a procedure in few parts

Tags: vb.net, code-organization

I'm having inside a textbox textchanged event a long procedure and I'd like to make it easier and lighter.
So, I'm trying to check what clipboard has and if it respect some parameters, it can goes forward.
I want basically to create a step by step thing.
So, I'm trying to clean the code :

Under main textbox textchanged event

```
    If (My.Settings.Dfolder = "") Then
     Label2.Text = "Download folder is missing "      
     Else
        If Clipboard.GetText.Contains("youtube") = False Then
            Label2.Text = "It doesn't contain a youtube link "
         Else
             If TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText Then
                 Label2.Text = "You are trying to use the same link"
              Else
                 TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText

           End If
       End If
    End If
```

So, this for me it works perfectly, as it makes it step by step and it doesn't go forward if the first if  statement is not respected.
The problems come when I want to go forward.
After "TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText" the program have to do following things:

1. Get documenttitle of youtube link(downloading it with webclient.downloadstring and Regular expression to get page title.
2. Check if title doesn't contain invali filename chars
3. Check with that title, if the file exist in download path or SubFolders
4. If file doesn't exist then the webbrowser(luckly is the only one ..) will start navigate to a page where the document completed event will get the "download link" (I'm downloading songs from an already existing online service) and it is using that link in order to create a QR Code by google api which will give me back the qr image.
5. Add to a richtextbox the title name as it has been downloaded.
6. then I'm adding the title name to an online notepad by a POST request(I know it is not professional, but I like it as it's working properly and also easier than manage(and pay) a database )
7. I'm displaying this notepad in a listbox(Betterlistbox1)
8. if the file exist(point #4) then It will just show to user where the file is located.

I have already coded all this but I'm using almost all of it inside a textbox textchanged event, Which is completely a mess. For example, if the connection is a bit slow or it misses signal for a second it will mess up all this procedure as it's working just if everything goes smoothly with good connection.
Also, the download is made by the link extracted from webbrowser, but I have to make a "oh my god" procedure. I'm filling a secondary textbox with the download link and the textchanged event is starting the async download.
It is basically a very fragile procedure, as If something doesn't work properly, or the webbrowser doesn't load in a reasonable amount of time, it will create delays , and delays here means not being able to make the next step. For example, after a while I realize that sometimes filename doesn't change, downloading song X as SongY, becuase the title extraction took a bit more than "normal".
My question is: How can I organize everything step by step?
Everything should start from beginning to end with logic. If the webbrowser is taking a bit more to load than all the process must be "aware" of the situation". Something like if webbrowser take 1 hour to grab the download link, then suddenly the next step is ready and working. I visualize this as a 7 × 100 metres relay.
The code I wrote is:

```
              'Under main textbox textchanged event
        Try
                'GETTING FILENAME FROM YOUTUBE LINK
                Dim x As New WebClient()
                x.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

                Dim source As String = x.DownloadString(TextBox1.Text.Replace(" - YouTube", ""))
                Dim title As String = Regex.Match(source, "\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups("Title").Value
                Dim a As String = title.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
                Dim webdecode As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a)

                Label13.Text = String.Join("-", webdecode.Split(IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars))
                Label2.Text = "Getting title "
                Label2.ForeColor = Color.ForestGreen

                Dim folderPatha = TextBox4.Text
                Dim filePatha = Directory.GetFiles(folderPatha,
                                          Label13.Text + ".mp3",
                                          SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault()

                If filePatha Is Nothing Then
                    WebBrowser1.Navigate("Download website" + TextBox1.Text.Replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", ""))
                   
                    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains(Label13.Text) = False Then
                        'ADD TITLE TO RTB1 
                        RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbLf + Label13.Text + Environment.NewLine)
              'extract the content of betterlistbox and  update the notepad online with this last title
                        Dim hey As String = (String.Join(vbLf, BetterListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)) + vbLf + "Inga - " + Label13.Text + vbLf)
                        
                        Dim ok As Boolean = SaveData(hey, "011hk762", "63958th7q")
                    End If

                Else

                        Dim risposta As String
                        risposta = MsgBox("File existing in " + vbLf + textbox4.text + "\" + Label13.Text + ".mp3" + vbLf + "Would you like to open the folder?", vbYesNo)
                        If risposta = vbYes Then
                            Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," & filePatha)
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                End If

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

While the timer that is updating BetterListbox from (online notepad) is:

```
Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        
        Dim task1 As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                         Try
                                             Dim res As String
                                             Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

                                             client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
                                             client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "")
                                             Dim stream = client.OpenRead("notepadonlinelink")
                                             Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
                                             
                                             res = (sr.ReadToEnd)


                                             'FILTER HTML TAGS
                                             Dim sourcestring As String = res

                                             Dim matchpattern As String = "<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>"
                                             Dim replacementstring As String = ""
                                             res = ((Regex.Replace(sourcestring, matchpattern, replacementstring)))
                                             Dim clientdecode As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(res)
                                             Label15.Text = clientdecode
                                         Catch ex As Exception
                                         End Try
                                         Try
                                             Me.Invoke(Sub()

                                                           Dim visibleItems As Integer = BetterListBox1.ClientSize.Height / BetterListBox1.ItemHeight

                                                           BetterListBox1.Items.Clear()

                                                             ' I add the value of notepad online in betterlistbox                                                           
 BetterListBox1.Items.AddRange(Split(Label15.Text, vbLf))                       
 BetterListBox1.TopIndex = Math.Max(BetterListBox1.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0)                                                                     
                                 
    
                       

                                    
             

                                                       End Sub)
                                         Catch ex As Exception
                                         End Try
                                     End Sub)
        Await task1
    End Sub
```

While the webbrowser document completed event got:

```
 Try



            'extracting download link
            Dim collection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

            For Each element As HtmlElement In collection
                If element.TagName = "A" Then
                    Dim link As String = element.GetAttribute("HREF")
                    If link.Length > 70 Then
                        link = link.ToString.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
                        TextBox3.Text = link
                        

                    End If

                End If
            Next
            '=====================================================================
            'and I'm gonna use it to create a qrcode
            Dim sitoGoogleQrCode As String = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs={WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}&cht=qr&chl={TESTO}"
            sitoGoogleQrCode = sitoGoogleQrCode.Replace("{WIDTH}", PictureBox1.Width.ToString()).Replace("{HEIGHT}", PictureBox1.Height.ToString()).Replace("{TESTO}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox3.Text))
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

            Dim bytes As Byte() = client.DownloadData(sitoGoogleQrCode)
            client.Dispose()
            Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
            Dim bmpQrCode As Bitmap = New Bitmap(memStream)
            PictureBox1.Image = bmpQrCode
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

And in another textbox textchanged event:

```
  Dim Path As String = TextBox4.Text
        Dim filepath As String = (Path + "\" + Label13.Text + ".mp3")
        mclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        mclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "")

        mclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(TextBox3.Text), filepath)
```

Thanks if you kept reading until here. I want to say that I know I'm making mess declaring variables many times as I cannot access the object. The code needs to be really clean, but for the moment, how can I organize all this?
Do I need to split the things and add them in classes and call them whenever I need ?

Many thanks

Comment: Too many things that need refactoring in this code. Most important: 1. don't use the `TextChanged` event for this kind of operations. 2. Don't `Invoke()` the UI Thread from a Task. Read the Docs, see what `Invoke()` is about, how it actually works, make some tests. You'll never use it anymore after (in this context). You have [IProgress<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) for that, or call `SyncronizationContext.Post()` directly, or `BeginInvoke()` if/when it won't cause harm. 3. Pass a `CancellationToken` to your Tasks. 4. Use HttpClient instead of WebClient.

Comment: [...] About the most direct question, try to have reusable class objects that exposes methods that perform single operations: One reads/parses an HTML Document, one Downloads a File, one gets a byte array and returns a Bitmap, one returns a MP3. Don't clutter the event handlers (even less packing a bunch of operations that are difficult to maintain - or to even understand why these have been written for - later), call a method from there that in turn calls the specialized methods that are needed in that context. Use worker threads when required. Try hard not to mix async and sync methods.

Comment: This question is too broad for us to answer; we'd basically have to rewrite your program. If you have a set of steps you go through, one of the simpler and nicely reliable approaches is to have a Timer, a variable that tracks state, and a set of operations in the timer tick depending on the current state. Each operation has an -ing and a -ed state (downloading, downloaded, renaming, renamed, processing, processed.. you get the idea). -ing can only progress to -ed by the function finishing doing the work, -ed can only progress to -ing by the timer tick. Don't use the UI thread for the -ing work

Comment: @CaiusJard I didn't ask to rewrite my program. Hope it didn't pass this message and if you consider this way, please don't feel pressure to understand the question.  I added the code I'm using to show what I am doing. Otherwise someone could say "show us the code you wrote" right? Wasn't it a good way to add the code I am using when asking a question? Thought it was. 
If you desire, I will replace all this code with a text list of 7 steps do to. Without any code. . Does it change anything? 
Anyway..

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your reply. Please also you, don't feel in duty to write my program! This is not what I want. 
So, following your steps:
1) What should I use instead of textchanged event, at least when I'm inserting the link on the main textbox? I can't see any other event that will call others methods. 
2) I decided to step out of that and I'm simply using a not async timer with 5 seconds interval. It will not create any problem to the stability of the program. Also, the timer is being started just when the User control is being created. After being disposed, the timer will not work.

Comment: @Jimi  3) It would be great to learn it, but actually I am not cancelling any request (while downloading)(maybe I'm wrong about how to use it. ..)
4) Can I ask you why httpclient would be better than webclient in this case?

Comment: @Jimi "call a method from there that in turn calls the specialized methods that are needed in that context. " That's basically the only idea I 'm having. . 
I want to minimaze the stress for the main form which contain a user control at its load event. . So, I will create many classes as the steps counts..
"One reads/parses an HTML Document, one Downloads a File, one gets a byte array and returns a Bitmap, one returns a MP3"

Comment: @jimi My question in this case is:  How to make sure that effectively the classes are doing what they are supposed to do in order to blind trust them and go to the next step(class) or when they need more time to process?
Which doc or an already existing project, example, I can have a look in order to make me an idea on how to create a good procedure for this context?
Thanks

Comment: @CaiusJard, it might be a solution, but I prefer not to "trust" the timer, or atleast I don't know how to use it for this long procedure. I can't trust it because if connection is missing the the interval will be messed up, right? If webbrowser is taking 1 hour to get the download link, the timer will not await for the webbrowser. 
Probably I am wrong, but I prefer to stay professional and make it as it 's supposed to be done. Thanks

Comment: There is no "supposed to be done" - you're the engineer, you decide how it is to be done. We can't design your program for you (it's against SO rules). I'm just saying from experience that you can have a Timer that ticks every second, and checks a variable status, if the status is still "downloading" then it can take no action. When the browser finishes downloading the completion event sets the status to "downloaded", then the timer will act on it 1 second later and move to processing. If the file stays in "downloading" for more than an hour, the timer can realize it, set status to errored...